# PHP/MySql simpler more efficient code

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using three different queries to output information from a db.. I've put a sample of what I'm doing below, I'm just curious if there is a more efficient simpler way of spitting out this same info.

I have a db table for events, that has a date field, and parent event field. I have to group the events by their date, spit out the events per each date, then spit out each sub-event underneath those events (by using the parent event field).

Below is a sample of how my code it layed out, I'm just not that good in mysql if there is an easier query etc.

Thanks

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events GROUP BY date");
while ($event_date = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo 'Date Header';

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date = '" . $event_date['date'] . "' && parent_id = ''");
    while ($event = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

        echo 'Event display code';

        $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date = '" . $event_date['date'] . "' && parent_id = '" . $event['id'] . "'");
        while ($event = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {

            echo 'Sub Event code';

        }
    }
}
```

To achieve a markup like the below.

```
<h3>Date 1</h3>
<div class="top-level-event">
    Some code
</div>
    <div class="sub-level-event">
        some sub level code
    </div>
    <div class="sub-level-event">
        some sub level code
    </div>

<h3>Date 2</h3>
<div class="top-level-event">
    Some code
</div>
    <div class="sub-level-event">
        some sub level code
    </div>
    <div class="sub-level-event">
        some sub level code
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one query:

```
SELECT * FROM events e1
LEFT JOIN events e2 ON e1.id=e2.parent_id AND e1.date=e2.date
WHERE e1.parent_id=''
ORDER BY e1.date
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? All this returns is all the results that don't have a parent_id assigned (IE: top level events). I guess this question was more asking about the php as well as the query. I'm just trying to determine if what I'm doing is overkill or if it can be done in a simpler way to achieve the following type html markup per distinct date in the db. I update my code with the type of markup I'm trying to achieve.